# Automatically convert all entity references in an object to hyperlinks in Jersey

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, moxy

Take a class similar to this:

```java
@XmlRootElement
public class Person extends AbstractEntity<Person> {
  public Integer id; // Actually in AbstractEntity
  public Person parent;
  public Person partner;
}
```

With a PersonResource.class containing the relevant `@Path`, `@GET` and similar method - with a base class that has a consistent "//{id}" method

This produces JSON similar to:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "parent": {
    "id": 2
  },
  "partner": {
    "id": 3
  }
}
```

I would instead like it to look like this (or similar, such that referenced objects are not partially or wholly 'embedded'):

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "parent": "/people/2",
  "partner": "/people/3"
}
```

And to be transparent to the entity, and other classes.

My current solution is to create a new annotation:

```java
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(TYPE)
public @interface AssignedResource {
    Class<? extends AbstractResource<? extends AbstractEntity<?>>> resource();
}
```

Then annotate each entity class with this, 'pointing' to the Resource class.
Then, in an instance of a `WriterInterceptor`:

```java
final AbstractEntity<?> ent = (AbstractEntity<?>) context.getEntity();
...
for (final Field entFields : ent.getClass().getDeclaredFields())
  try {
    if (entFields.getType().isAnnotationPresent(AssignedResource.class))
      context.getHeaders().add(HttpHeaders.LINK, 
        Link.fromPath(entFields.getType()
        .getAnnotation(AssignedResource.class)
        .resource()
        .getAnnotation(Path.class)
        .value() + "/" + ((AbstractEntity<?>) entFields.get(ent)).getId())
          .rel(entFields.getName())
          .build());
    } catch (final IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
      throw new InternalServerErrorException(e);
    }
```

Which kinda works, by adding some Link: headers. But it is hacky.

Is there a better (#define better more robust ideally using the framework and requires minimal changes to each class) way?